# Split me in two to keep things together

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> Keep me as one; I take things apart
>   Split me in two to keep things together

Hint:

> I don’t fix things! I take them apart from where they belong!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A rough answer is a

> bandit - one who robs others, so takes things (apart) from where they belong.

Split me in two to keep things together

> band it - wrap with a band to hold things together. The BAND-IT company makes fasteners.

Comment: I'm a little disappointed with this answer. I feel the first clue is a bit of a stretch and doesn't really feel 'right'. The wording could have probably been better.

Comment: @JamesCoyle TBH, I agree with you for my part; I initially wanted the first line to end with *I take things away* but thought it would be too obvious so went with this one to be metaphorical.

Answer (score 10):

You are

> Screwdriver

Since

> A screwdriver can be used to take things apart.

and

> Splitting will give **Screw** and **Driver**. A **screw** will join things together. And a **driver** can take/drive you close to someone you need.

Comment: Nice answer. Only that a screwdriver can be used to take things apart and fasten a screw as well :)

Answer (score 4):

You could be

> Roundup -> a herbicide which could be seen to "take things apart".

and

> Round up -> when you round things up you keep them together.

Comment: A little closer than the other answers, I must say :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are

> scissors

since

> when you keep me as one, you 'cut' things apart

and

> if you split me in two, you keep things together

hehe

Answer (score 3):

I'm going for

> **deconstruct**

Keep the word together and you take things apart.  Split it into two words:

> **de construct (said with a French accent)**

and you keep things together :)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! In here, we usually tend to produce answers with the spoiler tag (already done for you in the post). Nice try, by the way, but the answer is purely in English.

Answer (score 0):

Might you be a

> Cell

Keep me as one; I take things apart

> If you look at a single cell you have taken things apart to have 1 singular cell

Split me in two to keep things together

> Cells can split themselves in 2 (cell division) and cells make up bigger organisms so technically they keep things together

Answer (score 0):

Might be stretching it a bit but could it be

> Takeaway

because

> A takeaway is a restaurant or shop selling food to be eaten elsewhere.

and

> **Take Me Away (Together as One)** is a song from Paul Stanley.