# I greet the unfortunate, with my education

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

My prefix, mostly sturdy,
My suffix is a hill,
And my infix is eight.
Who is my whole?

Comment: Blatant ripoff of [Ebe Isaac's riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94861/5373). Since I couldn't solve that one, I made my own :-P

Comment: But *I like it*! Feel honoured to be honest :)

Comment: It seems obvious what the answer is -- but that prefix is baffling me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Answer #2

As this is not too far off from the first, I’m adding it as an edit.

> Prefix: **[Doc](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Doc)** the dwarf; dwarves are known to be sturdy. It may also mean [Doc]k as its complete form is sturdy (credits to @anodyne and clarification from @Rand)
>  Infix: **oct** for 8
>  Suffix: **tor** for high rocky hill
>  Whole: **doctor** treats the unfortunate with what he/she has learned.

#### Answer #1

Are you a

> **proctor**?

*My prefix, mostly sturdy,*

> **pro** (wrestler?), a person who is sturdy in profession.

*My suffix is a hill,*

> **tor** -- A high rocky hill

*And my infix is eight.*

> **oct** stands for 8

*Who is my whole?*

> A **proctor** is an official appointed for disciplinary enforcement in a University, usually to catch people cheating on exams. Those who are caught are most unfortunate.

Comment: Nope, but +1 because something is right.

Comment: Then are you a rot13(qbpgbe)?

Comment: For sure he is. But the prefix is a mystery to me.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Beats me. I’m now frantically trying to retrofit that prefix anyway I can to Rand’s description before going to bed.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation for the prefix any more than I do any of the ones I've been able to come up with. I think you're missing a couple of other subtleties: rot13(V guvax gur "rqhpngvba" va gur gvgyr ersref abg gb zrqvpny qbpgbef ohg gb ubyqref bs qrterrf yvxr CuQ, QFp, WQ; naq "Jub vf zl jubyr?" vf n ersrerapr gb gur GI frevrf _Qbpgbe Jub_.)

Comment: Your 2nd answer is correct, and what Gareth said in rot13s is also correct. The prefix is more than one letter though. What is sturdy?

Comment: Perhaps a rot13(qbp = qbpx)?

Comment: I did wonder about that @anodyne but it seems incredibly tenuous.

Comment: (Not to say it's _wrong_. I haven't thought of anything _not_ incredibly tenuous yet.)

Comment: @anodyne I was thinking along the same line but not sure if it would qualify as a prefix

Comment: rot13(Zl oebgure vf n QB, Qbpgbe bs Bfgrbcngul, N ovg qvssrerag guna na ZQ. Znlor fbzrguvat ersrevat gb gur B cneg, fgheqvarff bs obarf?) Just a thought. :)

Comment: Also went through that @MacGyver88 but was still skeptical.

Comment: Oh, no doubt, @Ébe. Still very stretchy. I just saw that and went, Hey, I know one of those! And he is fairly sturdy. :)

Comment: rot13(Qjneirf ner snzbhfyl fgheql, naq Qbp jnf bar bs gur frira qjnesf ...?!)

Comment: Great,@Rubio ! This is the best we got; adding it to the answer.

Comment: What @anodyne said is the intended thing for the prefix, with "mostly" to indicate it's not *exactly* the same word. Sorry that this was so tenuous :-/ I thought it would make sense, especially after getting the infix and suffix.

Comment: Well, @Randal'Thor I hope the edit would suffice

Comment: Yep it's fine now, I'll accept this. Sorry again about the prefix not being clear.

Comment: @Randal'Thor No problem, guess it even happens to the best of us :-) Take [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94772/split-me-in-two-to-keep-things-together) for example. Though I found the clues technically sound (even according to the dictionary definition!), the daily usage was found to be unacceptable to some so it ended up with a barrage of downvotes :( at least the majority was up-votes though.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Honestly, I didn't like that one. There were so many different things that seemed to fit the riddle well enough, and the intended solution relied on a company that many would never have heard of and a strange meaning of "take things apart".

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well, I’ll take your word for it :-) I’m taking a little more care regarding misleading clues for my riddles since then.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac That riddle was also pretty short and simple, so it's not surprising that it got many answers. Might be a good idea to make them a *little* bit longer (even 4 lines instead of 2) to ensure there's enough clues for a unique most correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not

> proctor or doctor

Could it be:

*My prefix, mostly sturdy,*

> a **bed** is mostly sturdy.

*My suffix is a hill,*

> **tor** means hill.

*And my infix is eight.*

> **oct** means eight.

*Who is my whole?*

> **bedoctor** - meaning: to confer a doctoral degree upon.
>  Before someone is bedoctored by someone who is already a doctor, they are **not** fortunate (or **un**fortunate) enough to be called doctor. "I greet the unfortunate, with my education"
> (if this is correct, then credits to @Ebe Isaac, @anodyne and clarification from @Rand al'Thor for comments on Ebe's Answer)

Comment: No, it [*is*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94886/i-greet-the-unfortunate-with-my-education/94917#comment271430_94887) EbeIsaac's 2nd answer. And I don't think this quite fits the "unfortunate" part. But you can have a +1 anyway for a good try.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I wasn't sure how far I should take the "wordplay" factor. I *was* stretching it... mostly it was the **"Who** is my whole?" is what was nagging at me. Also, I was pretty sure it was doctor as well (but you hadn't confirmed yet). Nice work Ebe. :-)